# HTTP ordering variables in form

Tags: php, forms

given a form like the following

```
<form action="/page" method="POST>
    <input type="hidden" name="input" value="12" />
    <input type="hidden" name="input" value="24" />
</form>
```

Using Google Chrome 31.x and PHP 5.5, `/page` now has a `$_POST` variable for `input` of `24`

This happens because when the $_POST array is created, The value is over written in the array. And the latter value is the value which is preserved.

Most browsers Ive tested this is the case, But Is there any HTTP spec / browser spec which says that form inputs should be sent in the order they are defined ? Or could an update in the future (or an old browser) send these updates in the reverse order for example ? or a random order ?

Edit:

to give more context, It will not be used like the above in all cases. only in a certain case.

The first form element is a SELECT box, But depending on the options chosen, Javascript will be able to change the value, Without changing the Select box value

Comment: You cannot have two form elements of the same name, unless used in an array.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i know, I want to use the latter value

Comment: Then, use a conditional statement based on the value you need.

Comment: @Fred-ii- both need to be present, One is a select, The other should over ride in rare cases

Comment: Again, conditional statements. `||` --- `&&` etc.

Comment: How would that conditional look ? i know what they are. but would it apply when submit is pressed ?

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['var1']) || isset($_POST['var2']) && !empty($_POST['var3'])){ // do something }` that's purely a mixed example.

Comment: Thats server side code, Not whats sent when form is submitted, The server code shouldnt need to change

Comment: Conditional statements are server-side code, how else would a conditional statement work? ;-)

Comment: Using javascript before it was sent was what i thought you meant

Comment: Personally, I tend to shy away from using JS when validating, UNLESS I use it in conjunction with pure PHP. JS can always be disabled. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of the order in which HTTP sends your two values, PHP can only have one value for `$_POST['input']`.

To solve this, use array notation:

```
<form action="/page" method="POST>
    <input type="hidden" name="input[]" value="12" />
    <input type="hidden" name="input[]" value="24" />
</form>
```

Now you'll have an array `$_POST['input']` with both values.

To answer your question about the spec, see this page:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4

See the bullets for the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` default content type.

> The control names/values are listed **in the order they appear in the document**. The name is separated from the value by '=' and name/value pairs are separated from each other by '&'.

Comment: I dont want both values. I want a single value of 24, What is happening is correct, But is that by chance or is there a spec which says its supposed to happen like that

Comment: @user1281385 So your first input is useless? Why in the world name two fields the same name, just to ignore/discard the first one?

Comment: the first input is not useless always, But injecting the second value will ensure that the first is over written. the first would be a standard form element which i want to ignore, the second would be a hidden value

Comment: @user1281385 updated my answer, I believe that's the spec you were looking for

Comment: Yeah Thats the spec, Thanks ! Ill accept in 5 mins. It wont let me accept sooner

Comment: is this the same for HTTP GET

Comment: @user1281385 The spec doesn't specify the form method in this particular case, I believe it applies to both.

Answer (score 0):

To my knoweledge there is no specification as to the order in which a browser should parse the from before submitting.

But I would say that you can pretty much assume that the form fields will be parsed from top to bottom, because the whole dom is parsed like this.

Here is a little bit additional information as to how a form submit is processed/handled.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls

Steve